# Why show the user 'There are n updates since page load, refresh to see them' rather than adding new data

Tags: data, loading, ajax

On a page which features a list of items (such as stack overflow questions or quora), the site often polls for data but instead of displaying that data it instructs the user to refresh the page to see them.

Since it's already making the request, why not just load that data with some sort of highlight to indicate that it's new.

Comment: I agree with the answer posted - however, consider that complexity of loading this data as opposed to loading say a label that says "X number of posts have been made...click to see them".

Comment: performance related. bad ux if you can't properly update your page without a serious lag

Comment: This might turn out to be a transitional problem. Todays browsers are very bad at page updates. Either they do a full page reflow, or they execute a lot of performance-degrading Javascript. A smart browser should offer an proprietary extension to extend existing pages smoothly.

Comment: @MSalters Why on earth would you want it to be proprietary?

Comment: @DanielF: Most innovation starts off being proprietary before it's standardized (e.g. `border-radius`) . It's rather hard to innovate and standardize at the same time.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Sudden rearrangement of content is disturbing

Dynamically updating data while user is looking at it may (depending on type of data) be disturbing to the user workflow - for example, if you're reading a sentence and it changes while you're doing it, it's unwanted.

The same applies for any content changes that will re-flow or reorder other content. Appending something at the bottom may be fine depending on the scrolling behavior, but still dangerous; but inserting or updating some content in the middle (e.g. discussion threads) will cause other content - likely including some sentence that you're reading at the moment - to be moved away from where it was. This is generally bad UX, as the user is suddenly forced away from what they were doing and they'll need to find the content once again to move on with reading.

Good examples of continuous automatic content updates tend to be either in-place updates (a counter or graph with changing values but fixed size and location) or append-only content (chat, logs) if the speed of new information is limited and expected by the user.

Comment: Another reason is a certain percentage of users won't care.  If there is a good reason to keep data up to date (stock quotes?), if some users want it updated, and some won't, you can give the user an option to "refresh data automatically" checkbox.

Comment: Having to find one's place to resume reading is one thing...clicking on the wrong link because it moved is another (and even worse UX).

Comment: If you ever want to see a prime example of this, try scrolling through a Facebook newsfeed in their mobile app.  It is a fairly frequent occurrence for me at all to be in the middle of reading a post and have it suddenly disappear from the veiwport, because the stories in my feed have been auto-updated.  I've spent as much as 30 seconds hunting down a post that I was readying in order to finish it, as a result of this behavior.  It is a very disruptive user experience.

Comment: We've got a bug tracking system that auto refreshes.  It's extremely irritating as what I was clicking on will on occasion move while I'm clicking.  That never ends well...

Comment: The impact of this can sometimes be lessened (though not eliminated) by a smooth glide type of motion when content is inserted above the user's current place. Then, at least, the user has a better chance to keep their place in reading, and clicking the wrong link shouldn't be an issue unless the links are very close together.

Comment: The critical bit for me here is that it risks interrupting the User's attention/focus. Anything that distracts the user from his/her current task had darn-well be important.  I'm looking at you, Windows and OSX 'App Store Update' notifications!

Comment: And aside from UX concerns, there may be a practicality issue development-wise.  Loading new content by refreshing the page (or through a link that essentially does the same thing) is something that works "for free".  Dynamically updating the content without a page load takes dedicated code to accomplish, both server and client side.  And depending upon your technology stack, architecture, and how much planning was done for the dynamic updates, implementing that code can be complicated/time-consuming.  Often, a 'click to reload' link is just plain easier to build.

Comment: Agreed. That's why asking questions on stackoverflow is an exercise in frustration. I'm flabbergasted why they didn't address this after so many years.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: YouTube is terrible for this. The page loads, there are no ads. Two seconds later, just as I'm about to tap on the first result, three ads slide in at that exact moment, and I accidently select one of them. I would use an advert blocker, but this is on my mobile where it's not possible. Irritates me to no end.

Comment: This happens in windows Programs and Features when listing everything installed and is very irritating when you actually see the program you want, click on it, and click uninstall, only to find you are actually about to uninstall something critical; like spotify!

Answer (score 17):

Additionally, it's less data intensive, and if you're designing with a [mobile first](http://www.lukew.com/resources/mobile_first.asp) philosophy, that's got to be a consideration.

- You're going to need to consider that the screen size is constrained
  to smaller dimensions than a desktop machine, which means that even
  smaller changes are more likely to move what the user is looking at
  off screen.
- Many (probably most) of your users will have limited data    on their
  data plans, so you want to make sure that their data allowance
  isn't unnecessarily consumed
- The data is often going to be slow so sluggishness leads to a feeling of poor performance.
- The devices may not be very powerful, so sluggishness is further exaggerated.

Comment: If you just make a request to get the count of new items, yes. Sometimes the client-side engine just pulls the whole content, shows the count and keeps the content in memory (or in a hidden section of the interface) until the user "accepts" to see it.

Comment: True. I would expect that when that happens it is often down to a poor or unoptimised implementation. Obviously if it's just text that is downloaded, the data consumption is considerably lower than with images. Some level of pre-loading of images will also help with the feeling of speed/performance, which is of course another aspect of the mobile experience for many users on mobile data plans, but the tradeoff is certainly something that should be considered, and I don't feel like the tradeoff is considered as heavily as it should be in many cases.

Comment: Please tell us more of the considerations and mobile first filosophy by editing your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you're halfway down a long page, say here on stackoverflow and friends, and  the top of the page changes without disturbing your current viewport, how will you know? Yes, it could bring up a banner "we just refreshed the top of this page with three new items", but the notice "there are N posts you haven't seen yet" gives you a chance to interact with your incoming queue when you're ready to look at them.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather used that way to avoid unnecessary disturbance. Social networks are using this scheme as well.

Comment: Is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: To be frank with you, I'm not aware of any name. But I've got another reason to use this pattern. If the user isn't interested in the new content he isn't going to click the refresh box. You save a lot of data while it isn't loaded.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34380)

Comment: @Devin Why this is not a valid answer?

Comment: This is an automated answer from the review process, someone flagged it as not an answer and some of us thought it really isn't an answer. However, it's not a valid answer because it's an opinion rather than an explained answer with factual data and or any kind of support. While I may or may not agree with these kind of answers, the idea of "because I say so" answers is not supported at UX.stackexchange. This is nothing personal, just the way reviewing works